# How to read a file into an array line by line c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

i've written this code and the file that i read contains 3 multiple choice questions. The program works fine and i can store answers but there is a problem. I need to randomize the order of questions every time i compile. The only way to do that is to read the file in arrays. I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Any help is appreciated. P.S i'm new to c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace  std;
int main()
{

    char c;
    char d;
    string line_;
    ifstream file_("mpchoice.txt");

    if (file_.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(file_, line_))
        {
            cout << line_ << '\n';
        }
        file_.close();
    }

    cout << "What is your response for number 1\n";
    cin >> c;

    if (c == 'A')
        cout << "That's wrong\n";
    cout << "What's your response for the second question\n";
    cin >> d;

    if (d == 'A'){
        cout << "That's correct\n";
    }
    else
        cout << "That's wrong\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first put every line into a `std::vector<std::string>` ([reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)) from the `<vector>` header:

```
ifstream file_("mpchoice.txt");
vector<string> lines;

if (file_.is_open())
{
    while (getline(file_, line_))
    {
        cout << line_ << '\n';
        lines.push_back(line_);
    }
    file_.close();
}
```

and then use `std::random_shuffle` ([reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/)) from the `<algorithm>` header:

```
random_shuffle(lines.begin(), lines.end());
```

Here's an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cfb326e24a846e4) that demonstrates the use of these standard library facilities.